# Zurb Foundation for Apps - not found page for undefined route

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm looking for a way to show a default view when a route is not found.  I can't seem to find a way to tie into the state manager or routing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file you can config

```
$urlProvider.otherwise('/');
```

to your desired path when a route is not found